# How do I fix this data type error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, case

When I insert the following into my query I get an error

```
,max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] else '' end)
```

`TotalPaid` is a field that contains, for example: `445.45`.

The message I receive is:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

but, this case statement works:

```
,max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then INSCOMP.ORG else '' end)
```

`Inscomp.Org` just gives the insurance company.

Comment: What is the data type of TOTALPAID column?

Comment: ,max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] else 0 end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

The field `TOTALPAID` is numeric. Case statement can return values of **same** datatype. You are trying to return a numeric value if the condition is met or a varchar value if it didn't. That is the problem.

**Solutions:**

1. You can cast a field to match the type of the other

   ```
   max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CAST(CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] as varchar(max)) else '' end)
   ```
2. You can return `NULL` if you want. There will not be any problem.

   ```
   max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] else NULL end)
   ```
3. Or just remove the "else" part

   ```
   max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] end)
   ```

   It will return NULL if the condition is not met.

Comment: that was easy... thanks

Comment: @JasonClark: Glad I could help, my friend

Answer (score 1):

All the branches of a `case` expression must return the same datatype. So you can't have one of them return `totalpaid`, which is a numeric column, and the other return `''`, which is a string literal. Instead, you could return an actual `null`:

```
max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] else null end)
```

Actually, since the default return value of a `case` expression is `null` anyway, you could just omit the `else` clause:

```
max(case when patins.rank = 1.0 then CLAIMS.[TOTALPAID] end)
```